# Can a view check if the page is 404?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My `404.blade.php` view is using my default layout, but if the page is 404 i want to hide some views I include in the default layout.
Is this possible?

Something like

```
@if ($page->notFound)
```

Or do I really have to create a custom layout to use in the 404 view.

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson 5.6.34

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Laravel 5.1, whenever an `HttpException` is thrown and handled by Laravel's exception handler the `Exception` will be passed the view as well (this will not be the case, however, for JSON responses).
So in your default layout you could have something like:

```
@if(isset($exception) && $exception->getStatusCode() == 404)

@endif
```

Comment: $exception is not set, when i print it I get an "Undefined variable"...

Comment: @JemoeE That's what the `isset()` is for. Have you definitely hit a route that doesn't exist?

Comment: Ah, it's because $exception is not set on 200 status-code pages, but on 404 it is set.

Comment: @JemoeE That's right. Sorry, I should have mentioned that. I'll updated my answer so it's clearer for others.